# Template setting is not saving in wordpress

Tags: customization, templates

I'm using a child theme. I want to override a template of base theme.
I created, `articles-page.php` which starts with:

```
<?php
/*
Template Name: Articles
*/
```

While creating a page in Wordpress I can see my template listed in the *Page Attributes* widget to my right. The problem is, when I change my template setting to "Articles" and hit update. It still shows `default`. My change is not being saved, hence my template is not being loaded for that page.

Answer (score 0):

Try naming the file `page-template-articles.php` but leave the file contents and header name - "Template Name: Articles" the same.

Right now, you might be running into a reserved naming collision within WP with how Custom Post Type templates are named, i.e. `articles-page.php` is a page template name for a CPT called *articles*.

Comment: I tried what you said but it didn't work. And I've tried using variety of compbinations like `page-template-xyz.php` with `Template Name: xyz` but still its not saving. I also tried using `xyz.php` & `xyz-page.php` with `Template Name: xyz` still no result.

Comment: What is the base theme? Try your page template as a child theme of a default WP theme, like twentytwelve and see if it works. If it does, it's a theme issue with your base theme.

Comment: Wow! I'm surprised to see that its not working with twentytwelve & twentythirteen as base themes. What else could be wrong?